# Relative positioning not working correctly CSS

Tags: html, css

so I'm trying to position my content box and its working fine for left, but when I try change the right value it doesn't allow. As you can see I have four images, but I want to show three, so therefore I'm trying to increase the right value so the box can only fit three (and also bring it in to the center a bit more)

I can get it to work by changing it to padding-right instead of right, but I don't understand why that works? My understanding is that : Padding = Distance between the content and the border, and right = how far from the edge?

Image: 
[image]
This is my content box code (the images are inside it in another box)

```
.imagesArea {
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
    left:100px;
    padding-right:180px;


}
```

Thanks

edit: html (removed some of the image code)

```
<div class="imagesArea">

<div class="images">
    <figure>
        <a href="photos/image1.jpg"><img src="photos/image1.jpg" alt=”Photo” width=150 height=150></a>
    <figcaption>Watch #1</figcaption>
    </figure>
    </div>

<div class="images">
    <figure>
        <a href="photos/image2.jpg"><img src="photos/image2.jpg" alt=”Photo” width=150 height=150></a>
    <figcaption>Watch #2</figcaption>
    </figure>

</div>

<div class="images">
    <figure>
       <a href="photos/image3.jpg"><img src="photos/image3.jpg" alt="Photo" width="150" height="150"></a>
        <figcaption>watch #3</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your html ,if possible fiddle it @ jsfiddle.net

Comment: sure, my html isn't really relevant though I don't think? because its basically just a box (the div) with another div inside it?

Comment: if i fiddle your data i get someting like this , jsfiddle.net/CBW39/ 
 which dosen't look like what is in the screen shot,so try to put proper code in fiddle update it and share us ur link ,images r not required

Comment: Here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/6v69M/

Comment: @AlexP2014 it is better to use ul>li>a>image insted of div for each image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of relative positioning is completely wrong. It sounds like you are confusing it with margins.

With relative positioning, the element is sized and positioned according to normal flow (i.e. as if it was statically positioned), and then the *whole box is offset* according to `left`/`right`/etc. This can cause it to overlap with other elements.

See [this example](http://jsbin.com/pedofudi/1/edit) for a visual representation.

It won't adjust the size of the box at all, so it will have no influence over how much content it can hold.

If you want to control how wide the element is, use `width`, `padding`, `border` and/or `margin`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin for inner content div **images**

```
.images{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

and set parent div

```
.imagesArea {
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
    left:100px;
    padding-right:180px;
    text_align:center;
}
```

As you want to show 3 images in a row, It will work for you.